# sending json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm sending a request from jquery and expecting json response. Configuration is like this:

```
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        iframe: true,
        dataType: "json",
```

Now there's a funny thing. When I return data as text, it works fine:

```
render :text => "{}"
```

But when I use `:json` option, firefox prompts me to download file containing exactly two characters, `{}`. Success callback is never invoked.

```
render :json => {}
```

Since there's already a workaround (see above), the question has only theoretical value. Did it ever happen to you?

Comment: Is your routing set up correctly? Try testing it out: `curl -H "Accept: application/json" -i -X GET  http://localhost:3000/projects/3`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to that you are setting iframe to true, so firefox shows the download prompt, either set

```
    iframe: false,
```

otherwise you have to make rails send the text/plain header by using

```
    render :text => "{}"
```

Regards.